# What is the difference between a cross-platform and platform-independant framework? Particular case of the Qt application framework

Tags: qt, cross-platform

I am a novice runner in Qt. Reading what Qt it is, I get confused in the meaning of some terms in web sites. Indeed I meet the term **cross-platform** framework, often **platform-independant** framework. I'd really like to understand the difference between these two group of words.

In the specific case of Qt, it is said that it is a cross-platform application framework
Please, Let me give you my thinking. I'd like to confirm that by someone else.
By Qt is a **cross-platform** framework, I myself understand the Qt source code is the same for each OS (Windows, Linux, Mac OS ...), but compilers used to build the source code which are different depending on OS. Is that true?
Contrary to a framework like java, that is an **independant-platform** since compiler is the same on any platform or OS.

Please tell me if my understanding is right/wrong about Qt and the meaning both a cross-platform and an independant-platform framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether I'm correct or not, I tend to think of it like this:

**multi-platform**: Different versions (possibly with different codebases) exist for more than one platform.

**platform-independent**: One codebase exists that tends not to rely on any platform-specific features or libraries, so *should* work on many different platforms without (source code) changes.  The code might rely only on the language features and standard library, for example, so is very generic.

**cross-platform**: One codebase exists for more than one platform, but it may sometimes use different sections of platform-specific code for different platforms where needed.

I don't think people rigidly follow any specific definitions for these terms, though, and often see them used interchangeably.

Comment: Do you think the Qt codebase changes depending of platform?

Comment: It has platform-specific implementations of some things, and the correct one for the current platform is selected at build time.  The external API might be the same, but some of the implementation (within Qt) is different for different platforms.